# Did Pilate know that during the arrest of Jesus, Jesus healed Malchus' ear?

Tags: john, luke

New American Standard Bible John 18:

> 3
> So Judas, having obtained the **Roman cohort** and officers from the chief priests and the Pharisees, came there with lanterns, torches, and weapons.

Roman soldiers were involved in the arrest of Jesus.

A miracle happened during the arrest, Luke 22:

> 49When Jesus’ followers saw what was going to happen, they said, “Lord, should we strike with our swords?” 50And one of them struck the servant of the high priest, cutting off his right ear.
>
> 51But Jesus answered, “No more of this!” And he touched the man’s [Malchus] ear and **healed** him.

John 18:

> 28Then the Jewish leaders took Jesus from Caiaphas to the palace of the Roman governor. By now it was early morning, and to avoid ceremonial uncleanness they did not enter the palace, because they wanted to be able to eat the Passover. 29So Pilate came out to them and asked, “What charges are you bringing against this man?”

Would Pilate have learned from the Roman cohort that a miracle happened during the arrest of Jesus?

Comment: We are not told.  We do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we have no indication that Pilate knew about this particular miracle, there is evidence that Pilate saw Jesus as more than an ordinary man because of his miracles.

> The Jews answered him, “We have a law, and xaccording to that law he ought to die because he has made himself the Son of God.” 8 When Pilate heard this statement, he was even more afraid. (John 19:7, ESV)

Although Pilate probably saw Jesus in terms consistent with Roman mythology.  Further evidence that Jesus' miracles were well known, the well-armed and militarily superior solders were fearful of Jesus.

> When Jesus said to them, “I am he,” they drew back and fell to the ground. (John 18:6)

What Jesus was doing reached Herod.

> Now wHerod the tetrarch heard about all that was happening, and he was perplexed, because it was said by some that xJohn had been raised from the dead, 8 by some that Elijah had appeared, and by others that one of the prophets of old had risen. 9 Herod said, “John I beheaded, but who is this about whom I hear such things?” And he sought to see him. (Luke 9:7-9, ESV)

> When Herod saw Jesus, he was very glad, for he had long desired to see him, because he had heard about him, and he was hoping to see some sign done by him. (Luke 23:8)

**Thus, while we do not know about this miracle in particular, it seems evident that Pilate knew that Jesus performed miracles.**